# Environment-specific distributions using sbt native packager

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to create/configure environment-specifc distributions (for development, quality and production) using the sbt native packager functionality available in Play (2.2). I tried to achieve this using the following settings in a build.sbt file:

```
val dev  = config("dev")  extend(Universal)
val qual = config("qual") extend(Universal)
val prod = config("prod") extend(Universal)


def distSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  inConfig(dev)(Seq(
    mappings in Universal <+= (resourceDirectory in Compile) map { dir =>
     println("dev")
     (dir / "start.bat.dev") -> "bin/start.bat"
     // additional mappings
   }
  )) ++
  inConfig(qual)(Seq(
    mappings in Universal <+= (resourceDirectory in Compile) map { dir =>
      println("qual")
      (dir / "start.bat.qual") -> "bin/start.bat"
      // additional mappings
    }
  )) ++
  inConfig(prod)(Seq(
    mappings in Universal <+= (resourceDirectory in Compile) map { dir =>
      println("prod")
      (dir / "start.bat.prod") -> "bin/start.bat"
      // additional mappings
    }
  ))


play.Project.playScalaSettings ++ distSettings
```

In the SBT console, when I'm typing "dev:dist" I was expecting to see only "dev" as output and correspondingly only the corresponding mappings to be used. Instead, it looks like all mappings across all configs are merged. Most likely I don't understand how configs are supposed to work in SBT. In addition, there might be better approaches which achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: Note: This question was already posted at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/gdTv_hPxBq0 but I decided that SO might be a better fit in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`inConfig(c)( settings )` means to use `c` as the configuration when it isn't explicitly specified in `settings`.  In the example, the configuration for `mappings` is specified to be `Universal`, so the mappings are all added to the `Universal` configuration and not the more specific one.

Instead, do:

```
inConfig(prod)(Seq(
  mappings <+= ...
))
```

That is, remove the `in Universal` part.

Note: because the more specific configurations like `prod` extend `Universal` they include the mappings from `Universal`.

Comment: Ok, I see. If I do this, however, I now get an error saying "References to undefined settings: <project>/prod:mappings from <project>/prod:mappings" (same for dev:mappings and qual:mappings).